# Python : Plot multiple columns in a single graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

df contains multiple columns  and the three columns I need to plot are

```
gen_1    gen_2    gen_3

M          M        M
F          M        M
F          F        F
F          F        M
F          M        F
```

To plot them in different graph

```
df.groupby('gen_1')['pid'].nunique().plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
df.groupby('gen_2')['pid'].nunique().plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
df.groupby('gen_3')['pid'].nunique().plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

But I need them in a single graph to compare.

Answer (score 0):

I never use the pandas plotting tools.  Plotting from pandas works fine, I just prefer to stick to my routine.  I create figures manually, so this is one option.  Here is an example:

```
import pylab as pl

fig = pl.figure(figsize=(3.25, 2.5))
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax0.bar(df.index, df.groupby('gen_1')['pid'].nunique())
ax0.bar(df.index, df.groupby('gen_2')['pid'].nunique())
ax0.bar(df.index, df.groupby('gen_3')['pid'].nunique())

fig.show()

pl.savefig("filename.png", bbox_inches="tight", dpi=500)
pl.close("all")
```

Comment: It gives an error `TypeError: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'height'`

Comment: @Krush23 I modified the code to show a more complete implementation.  You need to specify both "x" values and bar heights when calling bar from pylab.  I assumed the x-locations will be your dataframe index, but you need to adjust this as needed.  If you import pylab then run help(pylab.bar) you will see the associated documentation to help out.